# Echosign Form in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page where users fill in some information and submit a form.  After submitting, I need to give the user an Echosign document for signature within the Salesforce (VF) UI, that was generated based on the record that was just created (Custom object record).

I'm not very familiar with Echosign nor the general process of how things need to flow in this scenario.  Can anyone give me the general steps required in order to get me pointed in the right direction?

My initial thoughts are:

1. On submit of form, if condition is met, create Agreement record in SFDC
2. Get Agreement Id and use REST API to create an Echosign widget
3. redirect user to page that includes widget for signature (the user will always need to sign first)

Where I'm getting stuck is how to create the SFDC Agreement, and then use that to create the signature widget (if that's possible?).  Or if I have to take some other route.